# Dot product of of quaternion-rotated vectors

Tags: rotations, quaternions

I'm reading http://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/articles/Quaternions.pdf and it says "it is easy to show that the operation preserves dot-products." on the page 3. But how is it done? I tried to make a dot product of r' and r' using the formula for r' on that page but I couldn't make it to the conclusion. Could somebody explain how can it be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your notation. We know that $q\cdot q=1$ so that $q^*=q^{-1}$ so, using the properties in the previous page, we find:
$$
r'\cdot s'=(qrq^{-1})\cdot(qsq^{-1})=(qr)\cdot(qsq^{-1}q)=(qr)\cdot(qs)=(q\cdot q)(r \cdot s)=r \cdot s
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Following that part, it goes on to triple product (which I assume scalar triple product) to show it's not flip, but would it put a quaternion in the triple product just like you did with dot products?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, but a triple dot product does not exists because the dot product is an operation between two vectors (or quaternions) whose result is a scalar.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit vague, the same page 3 of http://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/articles/Quaternions.pdf says "Finally, we can show that the operation preserves triple products", I'm wondering how it's possible.